# Question about little-o

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I'm studying little-o properties and I'm stuck on this case in particular.

Is it correct to say $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ x^3+o(x^3) }{ x^4+o(x^4) }$ $=$ $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ x^3 }{ x^4 } = +\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be more readable if you rewrite it as$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ x^3+o(x^3) }{ x^4+o(x^4) } = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3 + \alpha(x)x^3}{x^4 + \beta(x)x^4}$$
where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ go to $0$ as $x\to 0$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3 + \alpha(x)x^3}{x^4 + \beta(x)x^4} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1 + \alpha(x)}{x + \beta(x)x} = \infty \tag{divided by $x^3$}$$
Note that $\alpha(x) = o(1)$ (as $x\to 0$) is another notation for infinite-small expressions around $0$; that is,
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ x^3+o(x^3) }{ x^4+o(x^4) } = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1 + o(1)}{x + o(x)} \tag{divided by $x^3$}$$
 <sup>[[More info about little-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation)]</sup>